# GetElementByID acting screwy

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, input, getelementbyid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<iframe src="https://www.bing.com/search?q=jvgvgvjhhyihu&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=jvgvgvjhhyihu&sc=0-8&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=2db2e5b5df3a4cdcbe955a6a0ead83f9" width="500" height="500" onload="loaded()" name="myframe" id="myframe"></iframe>
<script>
var myframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
function loaded(){
 myframe.document.getElementById("sb_form_q").value = 'hello';
alert();
myframe.document.getElementById("sb_form_go").submit();
}
    </script>
```

For some reason it is giving me an error "Unable to get property 'getElementById' of undefined or null reference" ?

Comment: You cannot access the document in a frame that comes from another domain (Same Origin Policy) - Imagine what would happen if this was possible and you loaded say a users banking website ...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access elements/contents of an iframe that has a different origin than yours, you cannot do this as it's strictly prohibited by browsers.

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Is there any way to do this then?

Comment: No... There is no way... otherwise stealing sensitive information would be waaaay to easy. As I stated in my answer, "It's strictly prohibited by browsers"